# What is cn axis of symmetry

Tags: organic-chemistry, symmetry

While reading about axis of symmentry and I'm not able to comprehend what does C infinite or rather n signify in a molecule

---

I know axis of symmetry is the axis along which rotation of molecule results in the same molecule so what does n or infinite signify. Animation could help i think so do let me know if theres an app for drawing 3d molecules

Comment: There are only two atoms in HCl, so you can rotate by any arbitrary number of degrees about the axis: infinitely many possibilities.

Comment: jmol or webmo(for easier UI), you can choose any, both show the symmetry elements, and perhaps you should ask this on Maths stack exchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is an infinite number of proper rotations around an axis to match the original of an object with its image -- the example of $\ce{HCl}$ in the example by `@EdV`, than this axis is $C_\infty{}$ and thus (all altogether) $C_{\infty{}v}$ like $\ce{HCN}$.  Otherwise $n$ is an integer number for any rotation $360^\circ{}/n$ for $n > 1$ ([a reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational_symmetry)).  Training (including tests) is possible at [Symmetry@Otterbein](https://symotter.org/); actually *both* for molecular symmetry, as well for some examples in crystallography, too.

---

You may use [Jmol](http://jmol.sourceforge.net/) to identify symmetry elements of molecules on your own, too.  Maybe you have a sketcher (like the [NIH PubChem Sketcher](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/edit3/index.html)) to draw a molecule, and export it in a format Jmol understands (e.g., MDL molfile `.mol`,  or `.pdb` frequently seen in biochem) which you may read by Jmol.  (The model kit included in Jmol may be a fallback to stitch the atoms together, too.)

Under File -> Console, you may access Jmol's text-based interface (CLI).  Let's assume we have a model of methane, $\ce{CH4}$, the analysis could proceed in the following sequence:

- type command `calculate pointgroup`, to be confirmed by enter. Jmol will scrutinize the current model's symmetry, and display the result to the CLI as `Td`.
- `show poingroup` will yield a listing of what Jmol identified.

  ```
  # 5 atoms


  Td    center  {0.0 0.0 0.0}

  Td    nC3 4   2
  Td    C3_1    {0.5773503, 0.5773503, 0.5773503}
  Td    C3_2    {0.5773503, 0.5773503, -0.5773503}
  Td    C3_3    {0.5773503, -0.5773503, 0.5773503}
  Td    C3_4    {0.5773503, -0.5773503, -0.5773503}

  Td    nC2 3   1
  Td    C2_1    {0.0, 0.0, -1.0}
  Td    C2_2    {0.0, -1.0, 0.0}
  Td    C2_3    {-1.0, 0.0, 0.0}

  Td    nS4 3   2
  Td    S4_1    {0.0, 0.0, -1.0}
  Td    S4_2    {0.0, -1.0, 0.0}
  Td    S4_3    {-1.0, 0.0, 0.0}

  Td    nCs 6   1
  Td    Cs_1    {-0.7071068, -0.7071068, 0.0}
  Td    Cs_2    {0.7071068, -0.7071068, 0.0}
  Td    Cs_3    {0.7071068, 0.0, 0.7071068}
  Td    Cs_4    {0.7071068, 0.0, -0.7071068}
  Td    Cs_5    {0.0, -0.7071068, -0.7071068}
  Td    Cs_6    {0.0, 0.7071068, -0.7071068}

  Td    type    nType   nUnique
  Td    E     1   1
  Td    Ci    0   0
  Td    Cs    6   6
  Td    Cn    7  11
  Td    Sn    3   6
  Td        TOTAL    24
  ```
- Command `draw pointgroup` triggers Jmol to display *all* elements identified at once, e.g.

  [image]

  To walk around the model, hold the left mouse key.  To change the scale of representation use (shift + left mouse button), to pan (Ctrl + Alt + left mouse button), etc.
- to revert to the previous state, type `undo`.  You may display symmetry elements groupwise, e.g. by `draw pointgroup Cn` to see only the $C_n$ axes:

  [image]

  or `draw pointgroup C3 2` to draw only the second $C_3$ axis

  [image]

(The underlying syntax is compiled [here](https://chemapps.stolaf.edu/jmol/docs/).  To dive deeper into Jmol's syntax, the teaching set with examples related to biochemistry by Nathan Silva and David Marcey [here](https://earth.callutheran.edu/Academic_Programs/Departments/BioDev/omm/jsmol/scripting/molmast.htm) offers a reference, too.)