# Software for determining symmetry elements and point group of drawn molecules

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, software, symmetry

The title represents my overall question. I would like to have a software that able to draw molecules (especially coordination complexes) and determine the symmetry elements and point group of the molecules. I have a PC with Windows 10 system and an iPad Pro.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coordination compounds / complexes may be a bit tricky in terms of «what do you define as a bond» (covalent / dative bond) and the convention what a stroke between atoms expresses (e.g. in the representation in compounds like ferrocene).  But if you already have a .mol or .pdb file in available, you could try [Jmol](http://jmol.sourceforge.net/):

[image]

([credit](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/139516/what-is-cn-axis-of-symmetry/139518#139518), includes some details how to use the program this way)

While the example is about methane as a simple organic molecule, Jmol is well capable to interact with crystal structure models, and displaying symmetries of the unit cell, too:

[image]

([credit](https://journals.iucr.org/j/issues/2010/05/02/kk5066/), Hanson, *J. Appl. Cryst.* **43**, 2010, 1250-1260 [open access])

including interactive galleries like [Symmetry@Otterbein](https://symotter.org/) both about molecular and crystal symmetries.